# angular date time model gives 1 day less

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

When i am binding date with angular model, the model variable gives value which is 1 day less from i actually selected, please see the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
       <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script> 
     </head>
     <body ng-app="app">
         <input type="date" ng-model="ddd">
         {{ddd}}
     </body>
```

Comment: IT could be the issue of timezone. Check if your filter set default or not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is returning the correct date. To display correctly do

```
<input type="date" ng-model="ddd">
     {{ddd | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```

Here {{ddd}} shows just the date object. You have to filter it into correct format to display correctly